# What's the point of putting a `ifdef` on the first line of a source file?

Tags: c

People use `ifdef` to control which part of the code should be compiled or not. It's usually put after some `include some_header`which defines or un-defines the thing in the `ifdef`. I saw some code (e.g., the **lame** test case in the [MiBench](http://vhosts.eecs.umich.edu/mibench/source.html)) where there is `ifdef` at the beginning of a source file, which makes the compiler ignore the whole source file directly. Can anyone tell me what's the point of writing code like this?

Comment: everything between `#ifdef 0` and `#endif` is totally ignored.

Comment: The file might be one part of a larger project, with options controlled from the makefile.

Comment: Are you perhaps talking about header guards? http://faculty.cs.niu.edu/~mcmahon/CS241/c241man/node90.html

Comment: show an exemple of what you mean

Comment: I'm not going to paw through all the code at the link you provided, but at face value, the code enclosed in the `ifdef` is being optioned for some reason. That could be because it's test code, or a feature not included in a particular build. Or an older version of something that was later changed but the programmer wanted to keep the old one for reference for a time. Could be any number of reasons.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard

Comment: @ryyker You do realize *lame* is an mp3 encoder, not an adjective in this case?

Comment: @JoãoNeto The "include guards" only work with `#ifndef` or `#if !defined()`. The C file linked in the question begins with `#ifdef`, not with `#ifndef`. And: It is a C file, not a header file.

Comment: @Jabberwocky: `#ifdef 0` is a syntax error :)

Comment: @WeatherVane thanks. The Makefile explanation makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The file `amiga_mpega.c` begins with an `#ifdef AMIGA_MPEGA` and ends with the corresponding `#endif`.

This has the effect that the file appears "empty" to the compiler if the macro `AMIGA_MPEGA` is not defined.

You do this if you compile a file whose content you actually don't want to have in the program you are building.

One (of different) situations where this makes sense is when you set up your project in a way that all C files in a certain directory are compiled. However, in some situations  you don't want to have all the C files in your project.

Your project may be written to work for different operating systems and some C files are intended for a certain operating system only.

Using a compiler switch (`-DAMIGA_MPEGA`) in your Makefile (or whatever build tool you use) you choose if you want to compile the C file or not. If you don't want to compile the C file, the C file is compiled anyway but due to the `#ifdef` the C file appears empty to the compiler so the actual content of the C file is not included into your program.

Comment: The last paragraph covers the key detail, that you can specify `-DAMIGA_MPEGA` on the command line to control whether or not the source file has any content that's included in the object file.  I would probably bring that up the answer to emphasize it more.